# How to know whether the sync process has been finished in redis?

Tags: redis, synchronization

It seems that the only way to sync data between redis servers is to use the command `slaveof`, but how to know whether the data has been replicated successfully? I mean, I want to be **notified** just after the sync done.

I've read some resource code of redis, mainly `replication.c`, and find nothing official. The only way I know for now, is to use redis command `info`, and check a specific flag by polling, which looks bad.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying, i.e. `slaveof`, is to sync data between Redis master and Redis slave. Whenever some data has been written to master, it will be sync to slave. So, technically, the sync will never be **DONE**.

If what you want is a snapshot of current data set, you can use the `BGSAVE` command to save the data set into an `RDB` file. With the `LASTSAVE` command, you can check if the `BGSAVE` has been done. Then copy the file to another host, and load it with Redis.